How can I reduce the characters in the following python code?
The following code is 47 characters.
print(("Ekki v","V")["COV"in input()]+"eikur!")

How can it be reduced to 46 or less?
I have even been brainstorming bitwise tricks but can not think of any way to do this. I am starting to think it is not possible to reduce this any further.
One idea I had was
print('Ekki veikur!'[4*('COV'in input()):])

but this does not correctly output the capital letter for Veikor.

what's the problem statement?

The problem statement is write python code to reduce the amount of characters while retaining the same logic and functionality.

I mean, what are the example inputs/outputs of the original problem, where have you sourced this from. For example, why COV and not just C

The code outputs a specific phrase based on whether the input contains the substring "COV". Specifically:
If "COV" is present, it outputs "Veikur!".
Otherwise, it outputs "Ekki veikur!".
The objective is to reduce the code to 46 or fewer characters while maintaining the same behavior. The original code is 47 characters long.

And this was sourced from a private problem set. I cannot say for certain wether the exact letter are relevant.

@Sisyphus I'm guessing the the COV is referring to COVID as the outputs are Icelandic for "Sick" and "Not sick".

You should put all of the requirements in your question. As it is, it can be hard to tell if your code can be golfed because of various possible side effects. For example, the answer you got works if outputting to STDERR works, but we have no way of knowing if that is acceptable right now.

Python 3.8 (pre-release), 46 bytes
You can use exit instead of print to save 1 byte. This displays the same for me in a terminal running on Windows and displays the string in the Debug section in TIO.
exit(("Ekki v","V")["COV"in input()]+"eikur!")

Try it online!
